# If date < TODAY, then count column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

silly excel question here:

I'm trying to count # of values in a column if a corresponding column containing dates are less than today's date. I'm not sure if this would need to be converted to numerical date format, but here is the gist of what I'm after:

[image: example here]

If column A is not TODAY(), then I want to count # of red/blue instances in column B. It seems relatively simple, but I'm getting unexpected responses such as FALSE or the formula is ignoring the condition that I only wish to count text strings that do not equal today's date.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"<" & TODAY())`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SUM(COUNTIFS()):

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,"<" & TODAY(),B:B,{"Red","Blue"}))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B7,"<>" & TODAY(),C2:C7,"=" & "RED")
=COUNTIFS(B2:B7,"<>" & TODAY(),C2:C7,"=" & "Blue")
```

Comment: Excuse me, but is or is not a solution to the question asked ?, is a way of solving it, the first answer gives a total regardless of color, in this response I give the option of counting the colors separately, which is the error in the answer for you to qualify negative?

Comment: please write me one example where this solution does not work, please, because i do not see any error, please note i put the name of the color before, to show that the total is for the color

Comment: also note that I vote for the other solution, but the objective of my answer is to show separately

Comment: i think the question was: "If column A is not TODAY(), then I want to count # of red/blue instances in column B"